# React Native: Get position updates for every one second

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

At the moment, I have this current code, which works but **not most of the time**. I sometimes get delays and does not update at all. I am aiming to get a **real time position updates**. The way I have done it is by having `setInterval()` function, and I have used inside `componentDidMount()`.

I have tried to have `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` but didn't work. Maybe I am using it in the wrong way.

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.state.interval = setInterval(() => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          (position) => {
            console.log("Pos: "+position.coords.speed);
            this.setState({
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude,
              speed: position.coords.speed,
              error: null,
            });
          },
          (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 0},
          );
      },1000);
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using [`watchPosition`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#watchposition)?

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same thing, and would like someone to answer this.   Code gets coordinates one time, and then never updates

Comment: @Bisclavret I don't know why it doesn't work. I fixed the problem by purely writing the code in obj-c to obtain the location, and then send the data to react-native

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by updating state at every x second:

```
import { Platform, View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    location: null,
    errorMessage: null,
  };

    _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Permission to access location was denied',
      });
    }

    let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});

    this.setState({ location });
};


  componentDidMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
      this.setState({
        errorMessage: 'Oops, this will not work on Sketch in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!',
      });
    } else {
      setInterval(this._getLocationAsync.bind(this),2000);
    }
  }




  render () {
    let text = 'Waiting..';
    if (this.state.errorMessage) {
      text = this.state.errorMessage;
    } else if (this.state.location) {
      text = JSON.stringify(this.state.location);
    }

     return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```